# update bcrypted pass node js and mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

Based on http://scotch.io/tutorials/javascript/easy-node-authentication-setup-and-local example I start creating a test app.
I have this code for updating a password:

```
 app.post('/admin/account', isLoggedIn, function(req, res, next) {
    var oldPass  = req.body.oldPass;
    var newPass  = req.body.newPass;
    req.flash('info', 'OK');
    req.flash('error', 'Old password incorrect');

    if (req.user.validPassword(oldPass)) {
        newPass = req.user.generateHash(newPass);

        User.findById(req.session.passport.user, function(err, p){
            if (!p)
                return next(new Error('Could not load Document'));
            else {
                p._doc.local.password = newPass;

                p.save(function(err) {
                    if (err)
                        console.log('error')
                    else
                        console.log('success')
                });
            }
        });

        res.render('admin/account.ejs', {
            menu : 'account',
            messageInfo: req.flash('info'),
            messageError: false
        });
    } else {
        res.render('admin/account.ejs', {
            menu : 'account',
            messageError: req.flash('error'),
            messageInfo: false
        });
    }
});
```

Everything seems to be working fine except for the fact that it won't update the password in the database.
I mean `req.session.passport.user` returns the correct userId (I have more users in collection), `req.session.passport.user` returns the correct bcrypted pass, the newPass is the correct new bcrypted pass and in the end in console prints `success`, but I have no idea what could be wrong. I also tried to use `findOne` instead of `findById` with no luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed , was just a newbie problem in this line:

```
p._doc.local.password = newPass;
```

correct is  :

```
 user.local.password = newPass;
```

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your User schema, it might be possible that the model is unaware that your password has been changed. I would try using Mongoose's `markModified` method (see http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#document_Document-markModified).

Comment: i added p.markModified("password"); before p.save ... did i miss something? As far as i understand the password inside schema is a string so doesn't really need markmodified , that's for mixed types and arrays